# Detect VOIDed invoices from quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbwc

Our system pulls lots of data from quickbooks using the QBWC/QBXML.
We also poll TxnDeletedQuery to get a list of deleted invoices, etc...

How do I query for or detect a 'Voided' invoice?  I don't see anything in the InvoiceQueryRs schema that would indicate a voided invoice.
Does quickbooks do anything but zero-out the line item quantities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing QuickBooks does when voiding is:

- sets the quantities/rates to zero
- adds a "VOID" string to the `Memo` field

To detect it,  you'd have to parse the `Memo` field and look at the rates/quantities. There's no way to filter by it in a query unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  Making sure I wasn't crazy.